# Array Length From Google Geolocation (Ionic)

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, google-api, ionic2

Could someone point me in the direction of the correct syntax to use to return the value of results from Google Place Search. Like if my search returned 5 locations, I would like to pull the value of 5 from my array and display that information in my app "5 places have been found!". I have managed to get a list of places nearby. But I am not sure how to get a value.

Right now I use this code to access the array of Google Places Search Results

```
goToDirectionPage(index){

      console.log(this.places);
      console.log("index" + index);
      let selectedPlace = this.places[index].geometry.location;

      console.log(selectedPlace);

      this.navCtrl.push(DirectionPage, {
        origin: this.currentLocation,
        destination: selectedPlace

      });
    }
```

Here is the code to the Google Places Search

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the DirectionPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-direction',
  templateUrl: 'direction.html',
})
export class DirectionPage {

  origin: any;
  destination: any;
  map: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.origin = navParams.get('origin');
    this.destination = navParams.get('destination');
    this.map = navParams.get('map');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.calculateRoute();

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DirectionPage');
  }

  calculateRoute(){
    let mapOptions = {
      center: this.origin,
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("directionMap"), mapOptions);

    let directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    let directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

    let request = {
      origin: this.origin,
      destination: this.destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
      if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionPanel'));
      }else{
        console.warn(status);
      }
    });

  }


}
```

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D00g2.jpg)

Comment: can you please include the relevent code and clarify what you want to do.  Are you saying you just want to display all items from a list of json in html?

Comment: @PhilipBrack code and image added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In places.html

```
    <ion-card>
       <ion-item ng-if = "places" >
       Places Found: {{places?.length}}
      </ion-item>
     </ion-card>  

    <ion-card id="result"> </ion-card>
      <button ion-item *ngFor = "let place of places; let i = index" (click)="goToDirectionPage(i)">
       {{place.name}} + <br/> {{place.vicinity}} <br /> Average Rating: {{place.rating}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
```